# Vee-validate does not validate until the form is submitted

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

The form should be validated as the user types in their input, not on submit. However, once the form initially loads, all of the fields show errors, but don't go away unless the validations passed when submitting.
Here is what it initially looks like:
[image]
Here is what it looks like before submitting:
[image]
And this is what it looks like after submitting:
[image]
Here is my code:

```
<script lang="ts">
export default {
  setup() {
    let infoMessage = ref('')

    const validationSchema = {
      name: string().required(),
      message: string().required(),
      hasWebsite: string(),
      email: string().email().required(),
      websiteAddress: string().url()
    }
    
    const formValidation = useForm({
      validationSchema: validationSchema,
      initialValues: {
        hasWebsite: 'no',
        websiteAddress: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        message: ''
      }
    })

    const submit = formValidation.handleSubmit(async (values) => {
      const currentBackgroundColor = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background

      console.log('submit', values)
      const submitResponse = await websiteDataStore.submitContactForm(values)
      infoMessage.value = submitResponse.message

      if (submitResponse.status === DbEditStatus.error) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background = 'red'
      } else {
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background = 'green'
      }

      setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background = currentBackgroundColor
      }, 10000)
    })

    return {
      values: formValidation.values,
      submit,
      errors: formValidation.errors,
      validationMeta: formValidation.meta,
      infoMessage
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <h1>Contact</h1>
  <h1 v-if="infoMessage">{{ infoMessage }}</h1>
  <form @submit="submit">
    <BaseTextInput label="Your Name" type="text" v-model="values.name" :error="errors.name" />
    <BaseTextInput
      label="Your email address"
      type="email"
      v-model="values.email"
      :error="errors.email"
    />
    <BaseSelect
      :choices="['yes', 'no']"
      v-model="values.hasWebsite"
      label="Do you currently have a website?"
      :selectedOption="values.hasWebsite"
      :error="errors.hasWebsite"
    />
    <BaseTextInput
      label="What is your website address?"
      type="text"
      v-model="values.websiteAddress"
      :error="errors.websiteAddress"
      v-if="values.hasWebsite === 'yes'"
    />
    <BaseTextInput
      label="Enter your message here:"
      type="text"
      v-model="values.message"
      :error="errors.message"
    />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Vee-Validate to validate text as it is entered (the `input` event):

```js
import { configure } from 'vee-validate';

configure({
  validateOnInput: true,
})
```

More information here: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/configuration#config-options